# retrieve static jsx files from public path in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to have a markup file in my public path. There is a notification toast which should be able to retrieve the markup and use it in its body.

Assume I have the following:

```
Const Toast = () => {

    const markup = useGetMarkup(externalUri.com/templates/myTemplate.html)

    return {
        <div>
           {markup}
        </div>
    }
}
```

and in my externalUri I have in my public/templates folder

```
export const MyTemplate = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is a test</p>
      <button>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I turn the .jsx to .html template? And how can I test this locally?

NB: I use a hashRouter, and this is stored in a blob storage.

I expect that I can go to: localhost:3000/templates/myTemplate.html to see my template.